# Java - Running JAR refuses to load file in the same directory

Tags: java, file, file-io, properties

Quick one. I'm trying to deploy a program, which borks at the following code. I want to read a properties file named, adequately, `properties`.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
InputStream is;
// First try - loading from the current directory
try {
    File f = new File("properties");
    is = new FileInputStream(f);
} catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
    fnfe.printStackTrace(System.err);
    is = null;
}
try {
    if (is == null) {
        // Try loading from classpath
        is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("properties");
    }
    //Load properties from the file (if found), else crash and burn.
    props.load(is);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(System.err);
}
```

Everything goes well when I run the program through Netbeans.

**When I run the JAR by itself, though**, I get two exceptions.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: properties (The system cannot find the file specified)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        .
        .
        .           
Exception in Application start method
Exception in Application stop method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        .
        .
        .
        (exception during props.load(is) because is == null)
```

I'm running the file from the "dist" folder. I've tried placing the properties file inside the folder with the jar, without result. Normally, the `properties` file is located in the root project folder.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try using an absolute path to File.  When you are asking for the file from the classpath, ensure the file is indeed on the classpath maybe by using the "-cp /some/dir" to the java VM options.  Also try using a leading slash character so the resource you are request has an absolute path like "/properties".  If you still have issue maybe confirm platform you are using and also the java VM starting options and command line.

Comment: It's supposed to be in the directory from which you are running the `java` command. Otherwise it's looking inside the Jar itself, which is your second `try`. Did you expect it to find it on the filesystem or in the jar?

Comment: If you want to read a file relative to the current directory, that file has to be in the directory that you're running the command from, not necessarily the directory that the jar is in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You read your file as a resource (`getResourceAsStream("properties");`). So it must be in the classpath. Perhaps in the jar directly or in a directory which you add to the classpath.

A jar is a zip file so you can open it with 7zip for example add your properties file to the jars root level and try it again.

Comment: This; when you use `getResourceAsStream` and related methods, you need to ensure that the resource loader can find it; namely, it must be in the classpath. There are ways of specifying to include resource files in whatever you are using to build your JAR (I don't know them in Netbeans, though), in addition to manually adding the resource to the JAR itself.

Comment: Manually adding a resource for production purposes is a no go. I only suggest a quick way to  check if it works.

Comment: Well, it seems like Netbeans should automatically package resource files in JARs by default, so long as they are on the classpath within the source folder somewhere. I know Eclipse has some options which disable this, or ignore non-Java files with build scripts, but I don't know if there's equivalent hassles in Netbeans.

Comment: I think he put the properties file in the root folder of the project and not in the source folder and netbeans adds this folder to the classpath automatically. But when building the jar, netbeans only puts resources from the source folder (and perhaps from a resource folder like maven) to the jar. But I'm not sure. I usually work with Eclise or Maven (Gradle ...)

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments, I built an absolute path generator based on the current run directory of the jar. Props to you, guys.

```
private String relativizer(String file) {
    URL url = RobotikosAnomologitos.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
    String urlString = url.toString();
    int firstSlash = urlString.indexOf("/");
    int targetSlash = urlString.lastIndexOf("/", urlString.length() - 2) + 1;

    return urlString.substring(firstSlash, targetSlash) + file;
}
```

So my new file-reading structure is:

```
        Properties props = new Properties();
        InputStream is;
        // First try - loading from the current directory
        try {
            File f = new File("properties");
            is = new FileInputStream(f);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
            fnfe.printStackTrace(System.err);
            is = null;
        }
        try {
            if (is == null) {
                // Try loading from classpath
                String pathToProps = relativizer("properties");       
                is = new FileInputStream(new File(pathToProps));
                //is = getClass().getResourceAsStream(pathToProps);
            }
            //Load properties from the file (if found), else crash and burn.
            props.load(is);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
        // Finally parse the properties. 
        //code here, bla bla
```

Comment: This will work but you did not load the props file from the classpath, only from the directory where the jar is located. In your origin code you read it from the classpath. But you must configure your classpath to the directory where the file is located or you put the file in the jar file.